# php me devuelve siempre 0

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Estoy haciendo un calculo para en php, recogido con jQuery y pasado en ajax. Todo esto dentro de un wordpress(pienso que esto no influye en el fallo). Despues de rellenar 3 campos (1 input y 2 select) debe enviarlo por ajax y el php sumar los valores y devolver la suma... pero no! siempre me devuelve 0 y ya no se que probar... Me podeis echa una mano?!?!

Sólo un aporte más, si en vez de enviar el objeto (valores), los envío los 3 por separado si que me suma los del select pero el input no.

Dejo mi código a continuación:

(fuctions.php)

```
  function calcular() {

    $result = $_REQUEST['data1'] + $_REQUEST['data2'] + $_REQUEST['data3'];
    echo $result;

      wp_die();
  }
  add_action('wp_ajax_calcular','calcular');
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_calcular','calcular');
```

(script.js)

// cálculo

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#importe').on('keyup',calculo);
    $('select#nFac').on('change',calculo);
    $('select#nDeuda').on('change',calculo);

    function calculo(evento) {
      let data1 = parseInt($("#importe").val());
      let data2 = parseInt($("select#nFac").val());
      let data3 = parseInt($("select#nDeuda").val());

      let valores = {
              "data1" : data1,
              "data2" : data2,
              "data3" : data3
      };

      $.ajax({
            url:   admin_url.ajax_url,
            data: {action:'calcular', valor:valores},
            type:  'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
                // console.log(data);
            }
      });
    }

});
```

Comment: ¿Y si es sólo para sumar por qué lo mandas al servidor? Lo puedes hacer ahí mismo: `function calculo(evento) {
      let data1 = parseInt($("#importe").val());
      let data2 = parseInt($("select#nFac").val());
      let data3 = parseInt($("select#nDeuda").val()); let total=data1+data2+data3; $('#result').html(total); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El primer nodo al que tienes que acceder es a valor, y luego a los datos, también no está de más que castees a entero en PHP

```
function calcular() {

    $result = (int) $_REQUEST['valor']['data1'] + (int) $_REQUEST['valor']['data2'] + (int) $_REQUEST['valor']['data3'];
    echo $result;

      wp_die();
  }
  add_action('wp_ajax_calcular','calcular');
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_calcular','calcular');
}
```

También te recomiendo que antes de mandar los valores valides si en verdad están definidos, esto para que llegue limpia la información a PHP

```
function calculo(evento) {
      let data1 = parseInt($("#importe").val());
      let data2 = parseInt($("select#nFac").val());
      let data3 = parseInt($("select#nDeuda").val());

if( data1 && data2 && data3 ){
      let valores = {
              "data1" : data1,
              "data2" : data2,
              "data3" : data3
      };

      $.ajax({
            url:   admin_url.ajax_url,
            data: {action:'calcular', valor:valores},
            type:  'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
                // console.log(data);
            }
      });
 }

else{
  alert('No existe uno o más valores');
}
}
```

Eso debería arreglar el problema

Comment: Ya me funciona! Muchas gracias Alberto por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código puede todavía optimizarse.

**¿Por qué hacer que el servidor haga un trabajo que debería hacer el cliente?**

La realidad de la comunicación cliente/servidor es la siguiente, por lo general:

```
1  servidor
n  clientes
```

Donde `n` puede ser 1, puede ser 1,000, puede ser 1,000,000.

Si los `n` clientes envían los datos al servidor para que éste los calcule, estás haciendo que el servidor haga `n` cálculos, aparte de las demás cosas que tiene que hacer y que le son propias.

Alguien podrá objetar que es algo banal tratándose de un simple cálculo de `a + b`. No lo es. Supongamos una página con miles de conexiones concurrentes enviando cada una dos valores `a` y `b` para que el servidor los calcule.

**¿Por qué no los calcula el cliente y se los manda ya calculados al servidor para que los procese, SOLAMENTE en caso de que esos datos se necesiten para algo en el servidor<kbd>1</kbd>?**

Ese problema de optimización lo veo muchísimo en preguntas planteadas aquí. Quizá es debido a que aprendemos de tutoriales mal hechos o porque ¿se le da poca importancia a esto?.

Yo llamaría a este principio: ***que cada uno haga lo que le corresponda***.

Si lo aplicamos en tu caso, el código sería:

#### En el cliente:

```
function calculo(evento) {
      let data1 = parseInt($("#importe").val());
      let data2 = parseInt($("select#nFac").val());
      let data3 = parseInt($("select#nDeuda").val());

if( data1 && data2 && data3 ){
      let total = data1+data2+data2;

      $.ajax({
            url:   admin_url.ajax_url,
            data: {action:'total', valor:total},
            type:  'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
                // console.log(data);
            }
      });
 }

else{
  alert('No existe uno o más valores');
}
}
```

#### En el servidor:

Podemos usar un operador ternario para que evalúe si en el `$_REQUEST` existe la clave `valor`, para asignarla a `$result` y si no le asignamos `NULL` o cualquier otro valor.

```
$result = (empty($_REQUEST['valor'])) ? NULL : $_REQUEST['valor'];
```

De ese modo el servidor queda libre de tener que sumar, porque la suma ya la hizo el cliente.

#### Otro aspecto sobre la optimización

Cuando trabajamos con varios datos, todavía la optimización se puede incorporar a la lógica del programa.

Supongamos que en vez de tres valores necesitemos sumar `n` valores que pueden ser 10, 34, 200...

A nivel de Javascript se puede optimizar agrupando esos valores por algún elemento en común, por ejemplo poniéndole `class="sumar"`  a cada uno de ellos y aplicando una suma dentro de un bucle a todos los elementos de esa clase. Así nos evitamos el `total= a + b + c + ... n`.

Y, si hubiera que hacerlo en el servidor, podríamos recurrir a funciones que nos ayudan a optimizar el código. Por ejemplo en este caso, se podrían sumar todos los valores que hay en el `$_REQUEST`  usando **[`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-sum.php)** del modo siguiente:

```
$result= (empty($_REQUEST['valor'])) ? NULL : array_sum($_REQUEST['valor']);
```

Hemos usado aquí también un operador ternario. Si hay datos en `$_REQUEST['valor']` nos sumará todos los valores que haya en el array. Esta solución es óptima si por algún motivo decides hacer la suma de los valores en el servidor y no en el cliente.

Espero sea de utilidad y ayude a plantearse siempre como solución aquella que sea más óptima.

**La optimización es un elemento fundamental a la hora programar**.

---

<kbd>1</kbd> <sub>Incluso en tu ejemplo, el servidor calcula los valores y **no hace absolutamente nada con ellos, los devuelve al cliente y el código Ajax muestra la suma en un contenedor del cliente**. (Esto sería como saber que `2+2=4` y pagarle el pasaje a alguien para que vaya a Australia llevando `2`+ `2`, te calcule cuánto es y que de vuelta te traiga el resultado ... exagero un poco, pero es así de absurdo. El dinero que inviertes pagando el pasaje aéreo significa recursos de red y de memoria del servidor que usas innecesariamente).</sub>

### PD

Aquí hay un ejemplo de tu código funcionando sin intervención alguna ni de Ajax ni del servidor.

```js
$(function() {

  $('#importe').on('keyup', calculo);
  $('#nFac').on('change', calculo);
  $('#nDeuda').on('change', calculo);

});

function calculo() {
  let data1 = parseInt($("#importe").val());
  let data2 = parseInt($("#nFac").val());
  let data3 = parseInt($("#nDeuda").val());
  let total = data1 + data2 + data3;
  $('#result').html(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="importe" type="number" placeholder="Escriba el importe">
<select id="nFac">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
</select>

<select id="nDeuda">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
</select>
<hr />
<h2>Total:</h2>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero tienes que el valor que mandas , luego ya despues tienes que tomar el valor a los datos.

Cualquier duda avisa

```
    function calcular() {

    $result = (int) $_REQUEST['valor']['data1'] + (int) $_REQUEST['valor']['data2'] + (int) $_REQUEST['valor']['data3'];


      wp_die();
  }
  add_action('wp_ajax_calcular','calcular');
  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_calcular','calcular');
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es curiosamente muy similar a la mía :3

Comment: Me faltaba eso! Gracias Luis.

Comment: Respuesta demasiado similar a la aceptada